# Amazon S3 Static Website Hosting and REST API Access?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm currently utilizing an S3 bucket's rest api to access images for my company's application. I've written lambda functions to help lighten the load on my application, but in order to utilize these functions I have to change the settings in my S3 bucket to act as a static website host. When I do this I can longer access the original rest api. I would like to utilize both the REST api and the static website url to make the transition from one to the other smooth, but I can't find any details about doing this. Is it even possible?

Rest API request example `https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucketname.mycompany.com/spacebackground.jpg`

Static Website Example
 `http://bucketname.mycompany.com.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/spacebackground(1)Full.jpg`

Once I change a bucket to static website host I get a "permanent redirect" http response.

Is it possible to utilize both?

Comment: When you say "REST API", do you mean that you are using the AWS S3 API to generate signed requests? Or are you just using REST as an anonymous user accessing public objects?

Comment: Using rest as anonymous user. The bucket contains public images that are pulled in by our web app.

Comment: I just noticed Kannaiyan's answer which is very good.

Comment: CloudFront is a good service, but it's the reason you are getting the redirect is not related to static website hosting.  That was a coincidence.  Your REST endpoint is wrong for buckets in Northern California.  When you first create a bucket, S3 can be a little more forgiving of this error, because it isn't sure whether you made the mistake, or whether S3 did, but after that, you will get the permanent redirect if you use the wrong endpoint.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thank you! I didn't realize the bucket I use in prod and my testing buckets are in different regions so I didn't expect the URL difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing the cloud service named CloudFront.

https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/

You can map both lambda and your static website to a single domain. For Example,

https://www.example.com/ --- will be a static site
https://www.example.com/api   -- belongs to API.

Create a CloudFront Distribution, configure your origins and Map to your url pattern.

You can also specify which url need to be self signed or which one to keep public as well.

It will be a breeze.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this out tomorrow but seems like it should solve my problem.